# Disable wpf winow when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working with wpf (MVVM). I see some software that disables the whole window and controls when a button is clicked and it work did not finish.

For example, if it is the code of button command :

```
Thread.Sleep(20000);
```

during this 20000 the whole window is disabled. (or any other time-consuming function)

Is it a good way? if yes how can I do it?
I know about `IsEnabled` property, but the code of software I saw does not contain it, so there must be a more general way or setting I think.

Comment: Why can't you set the `IsEnabled` property of your `MainWindow` to `false` and set it back once you're done with your work.

Comment: Honestly it is not they did in softwares that I saw the code , so there must be a more general way or setting.

Comment: If you'd seen those code, what's actually they do?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(20000)` blocks the current thread for 20 seconds. Why would you ever want to do this when a button is clicked? It makes no sense at all.

Comment: @mm8 please pay attention to "or any time consuming function"

Comment: @dhilmathy Noting special

Comment: @FASW: What do you mean? A single thread cannot both sleep and execute a "time consuming function" simultaneously. And if you execute the long-running method on another thread, you shouldn't block the UI thread.

Comment: @mm8 I wrote "or" but you say "and" a time consuming function , "or" and "and" are different,

Comment: @FASW: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you sure they are not using the `IsEnabled` property? I have previously seen it used as an attached property which is attached by styling so it is not directly obvious. Also in the code it will not necessarily be bound to a property called IsEnabled in the `ViewModel`. Using this is the most obvious and easiest way of doing it, what would be the reason for not doing it this way?

Comment: Quit it with the abusive edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a good way ?

No. You should never block the UI thread for several seconds. It's user-unfriendly and bad practice.

You should execute any potentially long-running method on a background thread. The easiest way to do this would be start a task and await it. You could of course disable the entire window during the time it takes for the task to complete if you want to, e.g.:

```
private async Task SomeLongRunningMethod()
{
    IsEnabled = false;
    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(20000));
    IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Either set the `IsEnabled` property of the window itself or set the source property of a view model if you adopt the MVVM design pattern. Either way, you shouldn't block the UI thread.